# Is it possible to get a work permit in Germany without a degree but with solid offer/contract as a software developer?

Tags: working-visas, germany

Currently I am living in Berlin with a regular residence permit. Recently I got a really good offer (45k € / year) from a software company based in Berlin. Do I have a chance to get a work permit?

Comment: Why do you call "a regular residence permit"?

Comment: I thought there might be different types of it.

Comment: Yes, there are. Which one do you have?

Comment: The title is aufenthaltstitel. Its a sticker in my passport it lasts for 6 months

Comment: "_Aufenthaltstitel_" is just the German word for "residence permit". There's another word on it and I think in your case it's "_Aufenthaltserlaubnis_". I'll write an answer soon.

Comment: How did you get it? As a student, visitor, smth else?

Comment: As an intern in a tech company for one year which will be end in feb 15th. And yes Aufenthaltserlaubnis is correct.

Comment: Well, it seems that a degree prescribes to have a high school degree for getting a work permit. However, having a job offer may be a very positive factor. I think, you should ask at the _Ausländerbehörde_.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I did it and in the same field.